# Get product using WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Well I'm trying to get WooCommerce product using `WP_Query`, with some of params

It gives me results but sort by product title is not working, also when I try adding a category in params it doesn't work.

here is what im trying:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$params = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
//    'category__in' => array(22),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $params );


$total_found_posts = $query->found_posts;
$total_page = ceil($total_found_posts / 20);
```

Any help appreciate

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query worked for me. Perhaps the issue is with how you extract the products and display them?

I implemented the following on one of my sites, and it listed the first 20 products in alphabetical order:

```
add_action('astra_header_before', 'entreprenerds_callback');
function entreprenerds_callback() {
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $params = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        // 'category__in' => array(22),
        'paged' => $paged,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $params );
    $total_found_posts = $query->found_posts;
    $total_page = ceil($total_found_posts / 20);

    echo "## " . $total_found_posts . " ##"; // shows me 51

    while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo get_the_title() . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Are you using the correct query object in your loop?

Answer (score 0):

Well, My query was working correctly, problem was my "Post Types Order" plugin which was adding extra condition to orderby clause.

i changed my params to this:

```
$params = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 20,
'ignore_custom_sort' => true,
'paged' => $paged,
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC'
```

);

and it worked as i wanted.